# BOOTMGR missing - depending on HDD

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, bootmgr

As I asked before

"I have windows 7 OS on my PC. I attached an additional internal HDD to my PC sometimes ago. Now when I unplug this HDD and start the system, My PC stuck & shows the booting failure message.

How can I unplug it since the drive has got many bad sectors and I'm not willing to use it any longer."

There are some additional detail. I attached one more HDD.Now

1. HDD00 [having windows 7]  [SLAVE]
2. HDD01 [which is puzzling me] [MASTER]
3. HDD02 [new] [SLAVE]

Now what combinations i tried and what problem i faced.

- If i attach HDD02, it is giving "BOOTMGR missing".
- If i detach HDD01 whether HDD02 is attached or not, it is giving "BOOTMGR missing"
- If i change booting sequence through BIOS or by pressing F12, same problem
- "HIREN BOOT CD 14" has an option "BOOT from Windows 7/2008/ VISTA". If i use this option then I am able to boot. But HDD01 is supposed to be attached, otherwise this option fails.
- I had tried making HDD02 as MASTER and HDD01 as SLAVE, still same problem
- I had installed Windows 7 on new drive, still same problem.
- I had tried many MBR tolls come with Hiren Boot CD. Nothing worked for me.

Suggest me some software or internal settings which can help me to get rid off HDD01 and booting system normally.

Please help ... I have open cabinet with a open problem :)

Comment: You need to show people the output of the `list disk` and `list partition` commands from within `diskpart` on your machine.  The above is not enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your BIOS to change Boot order.

Comment: I had tried. But it failed... I had updated the question accordingly

Comment: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/20864-mbr-restore-windows-7-master-boot-record.html

Comment: My problem has been solved. By detaching HDD01 and then installing Windows 7 on HDD02. I was facing problem since on every installation it was making bootmgr on primary partition of HDD01 only. After detaching HDD01, it made bootmgr file on HDD02. Well! you suggested link seems related to my problem (however, now i cant try it) so I am accepting your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try inserting the Windows 7 setup disk and selecting "Repair this system."  I've run into many systems where the boot info was never installed to the new HD and the uses had unknowingly had been booting off the old HD, which then directs BIOS to the new HD for the bootup process.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear in your post which disk is the system disk. It would be better if you rephrased it more clearly.
In any case, disk 0 is always the master, so I really don't understand your logic in the above description. What happens when you pull out all the disks except the boot disk ?

Is it possible that you have by mistake a 2-disk boot setup, where the boot files are on disk A and Windows is installed on disk B, and you are now trying to boot from disk B where there is no boot manager at all ? This normally occurs after installing a second operating system in a multi-boot configuration.

The solution in this case would be to pull out all the disks except that of Windows, and to "repair" the boot (which would actually install it for the first time).

See [How to Manually Repair Windows 7 Boot Loader Problems](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32523/how-to-manually-repair-windows-7-boot-loader-problems/).

Comment: I am not very aware with hardware config but on my mother board there are 3 sata ports together and one sata port is given separate. If i atached a HDD with last one port then that HDD becomes master and rest turns to slave

Comment: I do not know this motherboard, but in that case take out all disks and plug only the Windows one into the master slot, then follow my above link.